# How can I search a single word in apache Solr?

Tags: search, solr, indexing, solrj, stemming

I am using Apache Solr for indexing using DataImportHandler.
The document structure is as follows:

id(long), title(text), abstract(text), pubDate(date)

I combined title and abstract filed fro text searching.My problem is when I query
"title: utility" then it gives result as follows:

id,  title

6, Financial Deal Insights Energy & **Utilities** December 2008

11,Residential **utility** retail strategies in an economic downturn

16,Financial Deal Insights: Energy & **Utilities** Review of 2008

41,Solar at the heart of **utility** corporate strategy

I want to search only "utility" but it gives result also for utilities...
I also tried title:"utility" and title:utility~1 but it doesnt worked.
I read about 'stemming' but I dont have any idea how to use it...
please help me..
thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is cause of the PorterStemFilterFactory in your Text analysis.

```
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
```

Stemmer would reduce the words to root and hence utility would match utilities as well.

Check if you need Stemmer for Searching, else you can remove it from your filter chain.
Else check for a less aggressive stemmer to fit your needs.